# Ansible sudo default prompt

Tags: linux, ansible, sudo

When we issue a sudo request via ansible, ansible using the –p option of sudo to display a customized message (which is generated dynamically with each ansible run ) using the command

```
sudo -H -S  -p "[sudo via ansible, key=vrioenmynjfokqgzjxywtayyaivnxspy] password: " <command Name>
```

This has been observed via `-vvv` mode.

The problem is we have a situation where the default custom sudo prompt is fixed and cannot be overriden using `sudo -p` option (beause sudo access is verified via third-party tool Active directory).

Say for example:

```
sudo ls -l:
use Window's password:
```

If I use `sudo -p`

```
sudo -p 'Enter your password:' ls -l
use Window's password:
```

When ansible tries to do sudo , it expects the custom prompt and then if the expected custom prompt matched with the thrown custom prompt ansible sends the password, otherwise not and results in error (timeout)

My question is is there any way

```
sudo -H -S  -p "[sudo via ansible, key=vrioenmynjfokqgzjxywtayyaivnxspy]
```

the custom prompt using `-p` option in ansible can be made fixed for every ansible run using some configuration

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`ansible_become_exe` parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters) for a task, play, or in the inventory.

For example:

```
- name: Check escalation
  vars:
    ansible_become: true
    ansible_become_exe: 'sudo -p "[sudo via ansible, key=vrioenmynjfokqgzjxywtayyaivnxspy]"'
  command: whoami
```

Comment: This custom prompt [sudo via ansible, key=vrioenmynjfokqgzjxywtayyaivnxspy]" needs to be changed to **use Window's password:** . The solution is not working as the custom prompt remained same. I tried to change ansible_become_exe: 'sudo -p "use Window's password:"' but sill it's not working